Detach Terminal crashes all terminal instances
New install. Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS ~ installed Gimp, Libre Office, and Ink Scape... then added UBS Studio to record the bug.
So, I open a terminal window, and left-click the [+] (top left) to add an additional tab. In most cases if I then right-click that new tab and select Detach Terminal, it will abruptly close all terminal windows that I have open. In some cases this behavior will stop for a few iterations and then start again. Sometimes I have to add two more terminal tabs and select a middle tab among them to try and detach... I have yet to isolate a specific open/close pattern that is 100% reliable to produce this issue. However, it is consistent from a fresh reboot.
Since then I've been looking for a place to report the issue and share the video. I have the video on my google drive to show what I'm seeing happen. Thoughts are welcome.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BI9sBUFMcHAGbh7QK5joUJVUSzzjP7_b/view?usp=sharing
Atomkey.

Please fully update (snap refresh && apt autoclean && apt autoremove && apt update && apt dist-upgrade) your system and reboot. If still the problem persists, please look at tail -f /var/log/syslog or journalctl -f to find errors logged at the exact moment your terminal crashes. [Edit] your question and add the relevant information.

I think I've the same issue. I created a bug report on Launchpad.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/2089835
